# The following objects(s) are masked from 'package:datasets':

Tags: r, statistics, package, effects

So, I'm running an old version of R (2.14.0) on Mac OS X 10.10.1 and I can't load the "effects" package.  It took me long enough to track down all the dependencies I needed to install effects, but I still can't get it to load.  I have colorspace, lattice, grid, MASS, & nnet.  But when I input `library(effects)` I get the following output:

```
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: grid
Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: nnet
Loading required package: colorspace

Attaching package: ‘effects’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:datasets’:

    Titanic
```

When I search `?Titanic` I get:

```
Help on topic ‘Titanic’ was found in the following packages:

Package               Library
effects               /Users/zoe/Dropbox/Zoe_Folder/IPE/R-2.14.0/library
datasets              /Users/zoe/Dropbox/Zoe_Folder/IPE/R-2.14.0/library

Choose one 

1: Survival of Passengers on the Titanic {effects}
2: Survival of passengers on the Titanic {datasets}
```

What do I do?  (I can't use R 3 because I need a really specific statistical package for statistical ecology that only runs on R 2.)  I would really appreciate any insight!

Comment: I don't see the problem here? Is `effects` not loaded properly here?

Comment: That's just a notice about variable masking; that's not an error. Nothing you've shown here indicates the package did not load or work. Are you getting some other error?

Comment: Oh, haaa. Maybe there is no problem.  I'm just very new to R.  And I don't understand what it means for an object to be masked from a package.  Is it just a way of confining the two `Titanic` objects to their respective packages--so that they don't get mixed up?  I'm just trying to make a simple box plot, but no graph is appearing.  I thought it had to do with `effects`, but I guess it's something else then.  Thank you!

Comment: No, I'm not getting any other error messages.  Something else must be wrong :(  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing's wrong - it's loaded fine!

It's just saying you have two datasets with the same name defined in different packages. I imagine that they are the same, but if you wanted to use one or the other you could use:

```
effects::Titanic
datasets::Titanic
```

This will happen with functions as well as datasets. Same method to pick which function from which package.

Comment: Ah, sorry, just noticed that this was answered in the comments!